# Función ROUND para el tipo de dato Double (JAVA)

Tags: java, double

Estoy buscando alguna función que redondee un valor double, he visto varios ejemplos con tipos de datos long y bigDecimal pero no consigo una forma de redondear un double, si alguien sabe de un método le agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La siguiente función recibe como parámetro el valor del Double y el número de decimales que deseas redondear, espero te sirva:

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```

Para utilizar esta función simplemente sería así:

```
Double valor = round(5.568,2);
```

La variable tomará el valor de 5.57